# React Native webview source target twitter.com . Can't load twitter homepage timeline

Tags: react-native, twitter, webview

It's work!

```
<WebView
    source={{ uri: 'https://mobile.twitter.com' }}
/>
```

Not work!

```
<WebView
    source={{ uri: 'https://mobile.twitter.com' }}
    onMessage={(event) => { console.warn(event.nativeEvent.data) }}
/>
```

[image]

I can't load the homepage just by adding the onMessage method. How do I handle this?